# minimizing the product of rayleigh quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

The problem is:

$$\min_{\alpha}\frac{\alpha^T A \alpha}{\alpha^T\alpha}\frac{ \alpha^T B \alpha}{\alpha^T\alpha}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and positive definite matrix.
I think the explicit solution may be hard to find. If anyone have some reference?

Comment: You say "maximizing" in title, and min in the display. Which one is it?

Comment: One answer is to simply use Lagrange multipliers; in the end, this would mean solving a cubic equation in $\alpha$. Alternatively, an answer could be that you are looking "in the wrong space" for the answer - the proper vector space to look for an answer is $V \otimes V$, and you are looking in the diagonal subvariety (note: not even a vector subspace) of elements $v \otimes v$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a paper on [minimizing products of positive definite forms](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/110821196) that you should find very useful --- it gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the products of positive definite quadratic forms to be convex, which will help do the optimization.